# Does anyone know why this app is available to 0 devices?

Tags: android, filter, google-play, device

I have checked the manifest filters over and over and I can't figure it out.

Here is what the filters show as on the market:

[image: android market permissions]

Here's the app in advanced mode (it's activated):

[image: Advanced view of the uploaded APK]

Also, here's the permissions in the manifest:

[image: Manifest code]

Does anyone have any idea why my app is being filtered to be compatible with 0 devices?

Comment: Is your application free or did you define a price?

Comment: Free. Does that make a difference?

Comment: This can impact the country where the app is available, but that should not restrain the number of available devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I just noticed that the market was giving me this warning on upload:

[image: Market upload warnings]

These warnings were from my custom in-house library that made use of these 3rd party libraries. Even though I had them included in the android project, the market was looking for devices that had them natively. So my solution was to get rid of my home-built .JAR file in the android project,  and include the .Java files instead. The warning wasn't there on my next upload.

Now the compatibility looks like this:

[image: Device Compatibility Fixed]

Answer (score 1):

If i remember correctly, I think that this number will not be calculated until you publish your app. Just save and publish, and a few moments (hours) laters, the real number will appear.

Comment: I published the app yesterday and waited an over an hour and I couldn't install it on any of my devices (the devices I developed the app with). The APK has been activated for about 15 hours now, shouldn't that have updated the device count?

Thanks for the answer btw.

Comment: That's weird. The only think that's missing is a `targetSdkVersion` in your manifest, but that should'nt impact on filtering. Maybe a temporary bug in google play?

Comment: I've added the targetSDKVersion anyways, just in case, and still having the same problem.

Comment: I figured it out and posted the solution. Thanks

Comment: Along with NotACleverMan's solution, clicking activate on the apk file fixed the issue for me